# Mysql Select Multi Column in to single column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to change the three columns in to single column with all of the data can any one help

This is my Query

```
SELECT emp_id
     , testing_emp_id
     , bug_emp_id 
  FROM tbl_screen_incharge 
 WHERE project_id = "PRJ0016" 
   AND (emp_id!="" OR testing_emp_id!="" OR bug_emp_id!="" )
 GROUP 
    BY emp_id 
     , testing_emp_id
     , bug_emp_id;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the query you are using to get this output?

Comment: You can use contacting method to do that

Comment: SELECT emp_id,testing_emp_id,bug_emp_id FROM `tbl_screen_incharge` WHERE project_id="PRJ0016" AND (emp_id!="" OR testing_emp_id!="" OR bug_emp_id!="" )
GROUP BY emp_id,testing_emp_id,bug_emp_id;

Comment: Get rid of GROUP BY. It does nothing for you here except confuse the issue.

Comment: And see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `UNION` for this:

```
SELECT `tbl_screen_incharge`.`emp_id`
FROM `tbl_screen_incharge`
UNION
SELECT `tbl_screen_incharge`.`testing_emp_id`
FROM `tbl_screen_incharge`
```

I have tested this using my database.

Comment: Thank you friend but i am not getting the result

Comment: Thank you so much... for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) or [CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) to select all fields into a single field.

CONCAT:

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
        -> 'MySQL'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', NULL, 'QL');
        -> NULL
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(14.3);
        -> '14.3'
```

CONCAT_WS:

> CONCAT_WS() stands for Concatenate With Separator and is a special
>   form of CONCAT(). The first argument is the separator for the rest of
>   the arguments. The separator is added between the strings to be
>   concatenated. The separator can be a string, as can the rest of the
>   arguments. If the separator is NULL, the result is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','First name','Second name','Last Name');
        -> 'First name,Second name,Last Name'
mysql> SELECT CONCAT_WS(',','First name',NULL,'Last Name');
        -> 'First name,Last Name'
```

Or in your case you might want to try:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', emp_id, testing_emp_id, bug_emp_id) AS merged_result 
FROM `tbl_screen_incharge` 
WHERE project_id="PRJ0016" 
    AND (emp_id!="" OR testing_emp_id!="" OR bug_emp_id!="" )
GROUP BY emp_id,testing_emp_id,bug_emp_id;
```

Comment: thanks for your help... I got the answer by using UNION.